# urllib.urlopen not able to open url with page id

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

It seems like urlopen ignores everything after **?**. Same object returned for URL `https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search?Page=11` and `https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search?Page=1`. tried to escape question mark but no avail. much appreciated if anyone can share insights

```
urllib.urlopen('https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search?Page=11').read()
urllib.urlopen('https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search?Page=1').read()
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Python 2. You really should mention that, preferably with a tag. That URL works ok for me, using `urllib.urlopen` in Python 2.6.6

Comment: Works fine for me. It seems like you are simply not storing the result anywhere, i.e., you should do something like `x = urllib.urlopen(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

can you try following snippet and check if it works.

```
url = 'https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search?Page=11'
response = urllib.Request(url)
info = urllib.urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: I think I found the issue. the first time go to "https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search?Page=11" default to "https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search". this is problematic because crawler won't be able to crawl any page beyond  default page. my approach was loop through by page id. any suggestion how to make it work?

Comment: code snippet: 

for i in range(1, 10):
    page =  "https://apm.activecommunities.com/danvilleca/Activity_Search?Page=%d" % i
    r = urllib.urlopen(page).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")